# API call does seemingly block JavaFX code

Tags: java, events, javafx

Hey there I'm having a problem when I submit from a JavaFX view. On submit I want to achieve following chain:

1. Change the cursor to the waiting symbol
2. Set a label text 'loading...'
3. Make an API call
4. Set the label text to 'finished, please hit refresh'
5. Set the cursor back to default

I want to do this, because the API call does lock the rest of the (web-) view and I don't want a user to click around and cause the program to crash. I've written this code to implement my above described chain of events

```
Button submit = new Button();
submit.setPadding(new Insets(5));
submit.setText("Submit");
submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
            label.setText("loading...");
            System.out.println("loading");
            model.newRootNode(searchIndividual.getText(), Integer.valueOf(numberField.getText()));
            // This makes the API call
            System.out.println("finished");
            label.setText("Done! Please hit \'Refresh\'");
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
vbox.getChildren().add(submit);
```

Using the eclipse debugger I couldn't make the label text change visible, but the cursor seemed to work. Besides I used `sysouts()` to check if the code before and after the API call gets executet and it does print `loading` and `finished`. The label gets set to `Done! Please hit 'Refresh'` and it would set the cursor to `cursor.WAIT`, if I wouldn't override it later again.
Why does the code before the API call seemingly not execute? Or let's say give visual feedback?

Comment: Are you sure that the calls for cursor and text update before the API call are not visible, or if they happen so fast that you only see the updates after the API call?

Comment: Well, if I click the button everything else freezes. After about 13s it shows `Done! Please hit 'Refresh'` but nothing inbetween, no different cursor, no label saying `loading...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler is called from the ui thread and after you change the ui content, that thread is not free to refresh the scene. Do the long running operation on a different thread and let the ui thread continue to do it's job to fix this. You could simply use `Platform.runLater` to make changes to the ui from a non-ui thread you start or use [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), that is designed to do a job like this:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        // makes the long-running API call
        return null;
    }
};
task.setOnRunning((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
    // disable ui
});

task.setOnCancelled((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
    // reenable ui
    // handle cancel
});
task.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
    // reenable ui
    // handle succeed
});

task.setOnFailed((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
    // reenable ui
    // handle failed task e.g.:
    System.err.println("Oops, Error:");
    task.getException().printStackTrace(System.err);
});

Thread t = new Thread(task);
// thread shouldn't prevent program shutdown
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

Also note that the way you handled the exception the ui wouldn't be unlocked again if an exception was thrown since that part of the code is inside the block where the exception occurs.